# TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions

Tags: javascript, random, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to generate a 20 digit random number:

```js
let code = Math.floor(10000000000000000000n + Math.random() * 90000000000000000000n)
```

I have tried putting the numbers in `BigInt()` as well as adding a `n` after but still this error comes.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why BigInt demand explicit conversion from Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996921/why-bigint-demand-explicit-conversion-from-number)

Comment: you need to `Math.random()`  become to BigInt type

Comment: @LiuLei It throws an error saying `The number 0.9062354423176955 cannot be converted to a BigInt because it is not an integer`

Comment: yes. Bigint can only represent integer

Comment: @PeterO. I tried reading that answer but still no luck

Comment: @LiuLei I tried Explicit Conversion to all 3 values, still getting the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// An operation with a fractional result will be truncated when used with a BigInt.

const rounded = 5n / 2n
// ↪ 2n, not 2.5n

// BigInt value can only operator with same type

// random BigInt
BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))

// generate a 20 digit random number
BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000000000))
```

you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Hey, but I do need that `Math.random()` function since I'm trying to return a random 20 digit value. The truncating is not a problem though.