# javascript how to multiply BigInt ** 0.5?

Tags: javascript

i am converting python code to js but cannot resolve this one
x = int(num ** 0.5) (num is big integer)

how to calculate this in javascript BigInt ?

thanks i solved it

```
var num = BigInt("14564566644656456665555555555555555555555555545654645"); //example
num = BigInt(Math.round(parseInt(num.toString()) ** 0.5 )); // result is exact same as python tested more
```

Comment: what is `**`? Is this in JS or python? You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible.  See [TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591552/typeerror-cannot-mix-bigint-and-other-types-use-explicit-conversions) and [Why BigInt demand explicit conversion from Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996921/why-bigint-demand-explicit-conversion-from-number).  At a glance, it _appears_ that since `BigInt` is limited to _integers_ you can't do operations that would result in non-integer numbers, but I'm just scanning.

Comment: @decpk `**` has been a JavaScript operator for 5 years

Comment: am i stuck here?

Comment: npm bigint-isqrt

Comment: @Paul I'm aware that it is a part of JS for a long time but It was not clear whether OP is talking about `**` in python or in JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigDecimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript)

Comment: If you want to take the square root of a BigInt value, you'll have to write (or find) a BigInt oriented way of doing that. If the number is not a perfect square, you clearly cannot get an accurate BigInt result.

Comment: it seems we manually have to do long division to find the square root

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [bignumber.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js). You'll need to convert the BigInt to a BigNumber, compute the square root ([sqrt](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#sqrt)), and then round it to an integer with [toFixed](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#toFix):

```js
function sqrt( x ) {
  return BigInt( BigNumber( x ).sqrt().toFixed(0) );
}

console.log( sqrt( 14564566644656456665555555555555555555555555545654645n ).toString() );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bignumber.js@9.0.1/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Your current solutions in JavaScript and Python are off by 1897074225, because you are converting to floating point math which doesn't have enough precision for the BigInt you are using. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)